# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying install an app on an older Atrix, works fine on S3. Searching the forums the possible problem is the higher SDK version (Atrix is 4.0.4). Fix is setting the API level apparently.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

But when I run `cordova run android` the file updates by itself to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

What is causing this change?

Answer (score 3):

Had to edit config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <widget id="com.ionicframework.pushprint617926" version="0.0.1"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
 <name>app name</name>
 <description>
    An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
  Ionic Framework Team
</author>
 <content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/> <====== Changed to 10
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<feature name="StatusBar">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
</feature>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Your app id"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Than sync Your project.it will work